# Appium testing for micro usb and slots in android device using appium tool?

Tags: appium-android

It is possible to test micro USB and slots in android phones using appium tool or we can go with another tool?

Comment: What exactly are you testing the micro USB slots for? Just to see if they're working?

Comment: yes i want to test micro usb slot working or not

Comment: is this a test for debugging on the local development machine, or do you want to test if the end user's usb is working?

Comment: now i am trying for local development machine

Comment: hi @PeterDavidCarter  i am not geting any solution to test micro usb and slot using appium i want to test both scenario   local development machine and  the end user's usb.